# PowerDNS, how to set soa_edit_api from the API?

Tags: powerdns

I want to set the value of `soa_edit_api` and `soa_edit` on a zone that already exists to INCEPTION-INCREMENT. Can this be done [via the API](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/httpapi/api_spec/#zone-metadata)?  I need to trigger serial change and secondaries notifications once a RR is added, deleted or modified.

Now, still after any modification I need to run `pdnsutil increase-serial zonename`. So while I am able to add records via API calls on the fly, I cannot really propagate changes until I specifically increase the serial. So either there is a way to increase the serial via the API (is there?) or I need something like INCEPTION-INCREMENT set.

The backend is sqlite for now (and cannot change) but if I can change the zone's metadata via SQL command line also, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the API and curl to set your values, example:

```
curl -X PUT --data @mysettings.json -H 'X-API-Key: mykey' http://myhost:8081/api/v1/servers/localhost/zones/myzone.com.
```

mysettings.json file:

```
{
    "soa_edit_api": "INCEPTION-INCREMENT",
    "kind": "Master",
    "soa_edit": "INCEPTION-INCREMENT"
}
```